# PHP file is not working on 000webhost

Tags: php, html, json, ajax, xml

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <p id="demo"></p>


var xml=new XMLHttpRequest();
var url="department.php";
var data=document.getElementById("demo");
xml.open("GET", url, true);
xml.send();


xml.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status==200){
var file=JSON.parse(xml.responseText);
myFunction(file);
}
};
data.innerHTML="Fetching Data..........";

function myFunction(array){
var i=0;
var print="";

for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){

print+=array[i].ID;

}
data.innerHTML=print;
}
</script>
<script></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JSON file

```
[
{"Name":"Arman",
  "ID":"1312038"
},
{"Name":"Khalid",
  "ID":"1312024"
},

{"Name":"Robiul",
  "ID":"1312025"
}


]
```

PHP File

//

```
<?php 

    header('content-Type:application/json');
     $json_data=file_get_contents("student.json");
    echo $json_data;
    ?>
```

//

i put all this file in public_html directory.But when i run the department.html,the JSON file is not responding.[public_html folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BQTe.png).so why this is not working.Is there any configuration for PHP in 000webhost.or i have done some syntax error?when i directly used the "student.json" file in as "url" in "department.html",then it worked properly.

using **"student.json"** as **url** gives proper result.

```
var xml=new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url="student.json";
    var data=document.getElementById("demo");
    xml.open("GET", url, true);
    xml.send();
```

Comment: You have an unclosed `script` tag in your HTML. Also, you probably want to use `DOMContentLoaded`/`document.readyState` to fire your ajax request.

Comment: change '<p id="demo"></p> <script' to '<p id="demo"></p>'

Comment: You have not closed `<script` tag in your html file

Comment: You are now missing an opening `<script>` tag before `var xml=new XMLHttpRequest();`

Answer (score 1):

In PHP file change

```
$json_data=file_get_content("student.json");
```

to

```
$json_data=file_get_contents("student.json");
```

you missed the 's' at the end of file_get_contents.

If that does not work **check that PHP is enabled** by creating a new phpinfo.php file with the following contents

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Upload it to public_html directory and go to yourdomain.com/phpinfo.php in your browser, if php is enabled you will see a formatted page with all the specific details about the version installed on your server. If you do not have PHP enabled you may see a blank page or just the literal contents of the file.

Also, Your PHP file as above would return the same response as the JSON file (file_get_contents() does the same thing as a GET request. So you can bypass this by just changing the url for the XMLHttpRequest() to that of the JSON file.

Comment: i have checked the php version by uploading a phpinfo() function through  a phpinfo.php file,i have php in my server and its version is 5.2.17. and i have added an extra "s"  after the file_get_content.but still it's not working.

Comment: Please edit the posted PHP file in your question to match your changes.

Comment: i have edited and uploaded the new version of the php and html files.but still not working.

Comment: Please edit your **Question** to reflect the current file contents, thanks.